# Join same table returns some column repeat

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a confusing logic. I have a table `person_details`, it has a unique primary key `id` and foreign key `persid`. Another foreign key is `common_id`. The `common_id` is based on 1 and 2. If 1 ,that means `asset`. If 2, then that means `liability`.

The `person_details` table:

```
| id  |  details         |persid |  common_id |
|_____|__________________|_______|____________|  
  200   asset details     30         1
  201   asset details2    30         1
  203   liability detail  30         2
```

I want to get the asset and liability details separate and return a single join query. When I try a simple query it returns repeating entry of liability.

```
select   a.details assetdet, 
         b.details   liabdetails,
         a.common_id assetid,
         b.common_id liabId 
from person_details a 
join person_details b 
    on a.persid = b.persid  
where a.common_id = 1 and
      b.common_id = 2 and
      a.persid = 30
```

Now it returns:

```
|  assetdet     |   liabdetails   |   assetid  |   liabId | 
|_______________|_________________|____________|__________|
 asset details   liability detail      1           2
 asset details2  liability detail      1           2
```

I want to return

```
|  assetdet     |   liabdetails   |   assetid  |   liabId | 
|_______________|_________________|____________|__________|
 asset details   liability detail      1           2
 asset details2    null                1          null
```

Comment: Please explain your expected output

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you only want to join the first row from a group of assets with the first row from a group of liabilities.  If so, then one option would be to use a CTE and assign a row number to each record of the two groups.  Then use this in the join condition to make sure that only the first record for assets/liabilities matches up.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT id, details, persid, common_id,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY common_id ORDER BY id) rn
    FROM person_details
)

SELECT a.details assetdet,
       b.details liabdetails,
       a.common_id assetid,
       b.common_id liabId
FROM cte a 
LEFT JOIN cte b
    ON a.persid = b.persid AND
       a.rn = 1 AND
       b.rn = 1 AND
       b.common_id = 2 AND
       a.persid = 30
WHERE a.common_id = 1;
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To some extent this is seems like a modelling problem: `person_details` feels like it ought to be two tables. Anyway this solution uses subquery factory to split the table into two result sets and uses a left outer join. This will prevent duplication of Liability records.

```
with asst as (
    select id
           , details
           , persid
           , row_number() over (order by id) rn
    from person_details
    where common_id = 1
)
, liab as (
    select id
           , details
           , persid
           , row_number() over (order by id) rn
    from person_details
    where common_id = 2
)   
select asst.details as  asset_details
       , liab.details as liability_details
       , asst.common_id as asset_id
       , liab.common_id as liability_id
from asst 
left outer join liab
    on asst.persid = liab.persid
    and asst.rn = liab.rn
where asst.persid = 30
/
```

This solution solves the problem for the data you have posted. Where this won't work is when there are more Liability records than Asset records. In that case you need a full outer join.

Comment: it returns liability_details null for all rows